# find number of occurances of specific digit with a counter in C++

Tags: c++, numbers, counter, digit

I have a large number whereby i want to find the number of occurances of a specified digit. I wonder is using a counter will work. My code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( )
{
int number;
int n1;
int n2;
int n3;
int n4;
int n5;
int n6;
int n7;
int n8;
int n9;
int n10;
int digit;
int digitCounter = 0;


    cout << "Please enter a number between 100 to 2000000000." << endl; 
    cin >> number;

    cout << "Please enter a digit that you want to find the number of occurances." << endl;
    cin >> digit;

    if (number > 0)
    { 
     n1 = number % 10;
     n2 = (number/10) % 10;
     n3 = (number/100) % 10;
     n4 = (number/1000) % 10;
     n5 = (number/10000) % 10;
     n6 = (number/100000) % 10;
     n7 = (number/1000000) % 10;
     n8 = (number/10000000) % 10;
     n9 = (number/100000000) % 10;
     n10 = (number/100000000) % 10;

     if (n1 == digit)
     { digitCounter++;}

     else if (n2 == digit)
     { digitCounter++;}

     else if (n3 == digit)
     { digitCounter++;}

     else if (n4 == digit)
     { digitCounter++;}

     else if (n5 == digit)
     { digitCounter++;}

     else if (n6 == digit)
     { digitCounter++;}

     else if (n7 == digit)
     { digitCounter++;}

     else if (n8 == digit)
     { digitCounter++;}

     else if (n9 == digit)
     { digitCounter++;}

     else if (n10 == digit)
     { digitCounter++;}

     cout<< "The total number of occurances of " << digit << " in " << number <<" is "<<digitCounter<< endl;

     }
        else

        cout<< "You have entered an invalid number."<<endl;



system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

However the counter is not working. Can someone advise what wet wrong?
Any help is really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why not just convert the thing to a string and loop over the string?

Comment: we cant use string to do this, only can use mod. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your Else If's need to be If's. As it stands now you only go through one decision statement. As soon as it finds a match you're out.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    int n1;
    int n2;
    int n3;
    int n4;
    int n5;
    int n6;
    int n7;
    int n8;
    int n9;
    int n10;
    int digit;
    int digitCounter = 0;


    cout << "Please enter a number between 100 to 2000000000." << endl;
    cin >> number;

    cout << "Please enter a digit that you want to find the number of occurances." << endl;
    cin >> digit;

    if (number > 0)
    {
        n1 = number % 10;
        n2 = (number / 10) % 10;
        n3 = (number / 100) % 10;
        n4 = (number / 1000) % 10;
        n5 = (number / 10000) % 10;
        n6 = (number / 100000) % 10;
        n7 = (number / 1000000) % 10;
        n8 = (number / 10000000) % 10;
        n9 = (number / 100000000) % 10;
        n10 = (number / 100000000) % 10;

        if (n1 == digit)
        {
            digitCounter++;
        }

        if (n2 == digit)
        {
            digitCounter++;
        }

        if (n3 == digit)
        {
            digitCounter++;
        }

        if (n4 == digit)
        {
            digitCounter++;
        }

        if (n5 == digit)
        {
            digitCounter++;
        }

        if (n6 == digit)
        {
            digitCounter++;
        }

        if (n7 == digit)
        {
            digitCounter++;
        }

        if (n8 == digit)
        {
            digitCounter++;
        }

        if (n9 == digit)
        {
            digitCounter++;
        }

        if (n10 == digit)
        {
            digitCounter++;
        }

        cout << "The total number of occurances of " << digit << " in " << number << " is " << digitCounter << endl;

    }
    else

        cout << "You have entered an invalid number." << endl;



    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: There should be only one if and a loop

Comment: I agree, that is a better solution to the problem. I was just trying to answer the question of what went wrong with the given solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your number into a string after that you search the digit in the string it's simpler.
Or you can read a character string (number) and a character (digit) and then you do like that :

```
char number[20], digit;
int count = 0, i;
printf("\nEnter a string : ");
scanf("%s", &number);

printf("\nEnter the character to be searched : ");
scanf("%c", &digit);

for (i = 0; number[i] != '\0'; i++) {
  if (number[i] == digit)
     count++;
}

if (count == 0)
  printf("\nCharacter '%c'is not present", digit);
else
  printf("\nOccurence of character '%c' : %d", digit, count);`
```

Comment: I doubt it is really simpler

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  unsigned long long large(0);

  int digitToFind(0);

  std::cout << "enter a large number [100 to 2000000000]" << std::endl;
  std::cin >> large;

  if (large < 100 || large > 2000000000) {
    std::cout << "invalid input." << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  std::cout << "enter the digit to find" << std::endl;
  std::cin >> digitToFind;

  if (digitToFind < 0 || digitToFind > 9) {
    std::cout << "invalid input." << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  std::size_t counts[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

  while (large > 0) {
    int rem = large % 10;

    counts[rem]++;

    large /= 10;
  }

  std::cout << "number of occurrances of " << digitToFind << " is "
            << counts[digitToFind] << std::endl;

  std::cout << "press enter to continue" << std::endl;
  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the sample codes contain another flaw: if the number is small then we get more zeroes than necessary...we cannot assume that the number is necessarily big.
This works for each number, in Python only because I'm more used to Python at the moment, it is straightforward to convert it to C:

```
N = 1230533007
digitToFind = 3
digitCount = 0

while N > 0:
    d = N % 10
    if d == digitToFind:
        digitCount += 1
    N //= 10

print digitCount
```